# OOP Basic question about compositions, inheritances and polymorphisms

Tags: c++, algorithm, oop, data-structures

I have [this code](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/VC45g3BTbX/) and I want to know if it has these three concepts : compositions, inheritances and
polymorphisms.(and if it doesn't have them how do i use them in the code)

plase help.

Comment: This looks like code taught by someone who learned C++ in the 80s and never bothered to stay up to date since then. Throw out whatever tutorial you're learning C++ from and find a more modern one.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Hey, at least it's `const double PI = 3.1415;` and not `#define PI 3.1415`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of composition:  a Circle is composed of a Point and a radius:

```
class Circle : public Shape
{
private:
    Point center;
    double radius;
```

Here is an example of inheritance:  a Rectangle is type of Shape:

```
class Rectangle : public Shape
```

Here is an example of polymorphism:  The `getArea()` method is declared as a virtual method in the base class (`Shape`) and then reimplemented in a different (subclass-appropriate) way for each of the subclasses:

```
class Shape
{
public:
    virtual double getArea() {};
```

[...]

```
class Circle : public Shape
{
    double getArea() {
        return radius * radius * PI;
    }
```

[...]

```
class Rectangle : public Shape
{
    double getArea() {
        return getWidth() * getHeight();
    }
```